# editable form with angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an editable table [image] It works fine, but i have to hide editable row and show that on button click 
for example. how I can do this?

```
<td contenteditable='true'>
                        <label class="text">
                              <input type="text" ng-model="medication.description" ng-change="editMedication(medication)"/>
                            {{medication.description}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label for="edit">
                                <input type="button" id = "edit" ng-model="medication" ng-change="editMedication(medication)" >
                            </label>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                </table>
```

Comment: add `ng-if="_show_editable_row == true"` in the markup, and in the controller add `$scope.show_editable_row = function() { $scope._show_editable_row = true; }`  . On the button add `ng-click="show_editable_row();"`

Comment: done, but still doesn't hide

Comment: check the console, you may have a syntax error. I use it in my projects.

Comment: <td contenteditable='true' >
         <label class="text">
               <input type="text" ng-if="_show_editable_row == true" ng-model="medication.description" ng-change="editMedication(medication)"/>
            {{medication.description}}
         </label>
         </td>
         <td>
           <input type="button" ng-click="show_editable_row();" id = "edit">
        
         </td>

Comment: and I add code to controller. But nothing...please help

Answer (score 1):

you should use [angular-xeditable](https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-row), using this you will be able to create table `Editable column`, `Editable row` and `Editable table`